# stop bundler (or whatever) from adding ".pre.dev" to gem version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

My Gemfile contains a line like this ...

```
  gem 'mygem',    :git => "git@github.com:me/mygem.git", :tag => '1.2.3'
```

The actual gemspec contains this code, which versions the gem automatically, based on the SHA you have checked out ...

```
s.version     = begin
  head_sha          = %x{git rev-parse HEAD}.strip
  tag_version       = %x{git name-rev --tags --name-only #{head_sha}}.strip
  untracked_files   = (%x{git ls-files --others --exclude-standard}.strip != '')
  _diff_status_only =  %x{git diff --quiet --exit-code HEAD}
  head_diff         = ($?.exitstatus != 0)

  version = (tag_version =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/) ? tag_version : "0.0.0.#{head_sha[0..7]}"
  dev_tag = (untracked_files || head_diff) ? '-dev' : ''

  version + dev_tag
end
```

... and this works. If I checkout a tag and run "gem build mygem.gemspec" it versions itself properly.

The problem is that today, for some reason, and it could have anything to do with new rubygems, new bundler, new version of ruby interpreter, when bundler fetches that gem, and installs, the resulting Gemfile.lock looks like this ...

```
GIT
  remote: git@github.com:me/mygem.git
  revision: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
  tag: 1.2.3
  specs:
    mygem (1.2.3.pre.dev)
```

Which component decided to add ".pre.dev" to the version number?

How do I make it stop?

Comment: If anyone wants to play with a self versioning gem, I have one at https://github.com/the-michael-toy/nullgem ... there is only one version 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

As I feared when I posted this, this turns out to be user error.

```
% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
% ruby -e 'puts  Gem::Specification.load("nullgem.gemspec").version'
1.0.0
% touch file_not_in_git
% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    file_not_in_git

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
% ruby -e 'puts  Gem::Specification.load("nullgem.gemspec").version'
1.0.0.pre.dev
```

When the self versioning gem decides it is version "1.0.0" with some local changes and versions itself as "1.0.0-dev", Gem::Specification.load generates a gem version of '1.2.3.pre.dev'

The problem is the actual broken gem (not this test gem), has an native extension to build, and when that runs, it creates files in the directory which
cause the gem to version itself as "-dev".

The "bug" is in the self versioning code, not anything in bundler or the gem system.